# como hacer para que value cargue sin que el usuario introdusca un digito

Tags: jquery, ajax

quiero hacer que esto que tengo en html:

```
            <div align="center">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <center>
         <table class="calculadora" border="0">
            <tr><td style="text-align:center"><h5>Calculator</h5></td>  </tr>
            <tr><td>I want to spend:</td></tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><input type="number" value="1" placeholder="Money in USD" name="Money" id="Money" onkeyup="busqueda();"/></td>  </tr>
            <tr><td>USD TO BTC AND HTG</td></tr>
            <tr><td><div id="numberbtc"></div></td></tr>
            <tr><td style="text-align:center"><input type="text" name="valor_Crypto" value="USDTOBTC" id="valor_Crypto"  style="visibility:hidden" required/></td></tr>

        </table>
</center>
            </div>
```

con este script de ajax:

```
function busqueda(){
    var valor_Crypto = document.getElementById("valor_Crypto").value;
    var Money = document.getElementById("Money").value;
    var parametros = {
        "valor_Crypto": $("#valor_Crypto").val(),
        "Money": $("#Money").val(),
        "valor_Crypto" : valor_Crypto,
        "Money" : Money
    };

    $.ajax({
        data: parametros,
        url:"js/valida.php",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(responce){
            //$("#values").val(responce);
            $("#numberbtc").html(responce);

        }
    });

}
```

cuanto el usuario cargue la web el **value="1"** cargue de inmediato y despues el usuario pueda poner su numero ¿como le hago?¿Que hace falta? estoy con ajax y jquery, gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a que al iniciar se ejecute `busqueda()` ?

Comment: si es con un onload="busqueda();" en body no?

Answer (score 0):

dentro de `<body>` cambiar y colocar asi:

```
<body onload="busqueda();">
```

con eso cargara el dato al terminar de cargar o actualizar la web